# eventStore.saveCalendar returns an error "json error: An unexpected error occurred."

Tags: swift, eventkit

I am trying to implement the same code in https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/06/17/creating-calendars-with-event-kit-and-swift/, but I get an error stating "json error: An unexpected error occurred." I am developing this project for macOS.

This is my following code,

```
@IBAction func addPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {

    // Create an Event Store instance
    let eventStore = EKEventStore();

    // Use Event Store to create a new calendar instance
    // Configure its title
    let newCalendar = EKCalendar(for: .event, eventStore: eventStore)

    // Probably want to prevent someone from saving a calendar
    // if they don't type in a name...
    newCalendar.title = "DCU"

    // Access list of available sources from the Event Store
    let sourcesInEventStore = eventStore.sources

    // Filter the available sources and select the "Local" source to assign to the new calendar's
    // source property
    newCalendar.source = sourcesInEventStore.filter{
        (source: EKSource) -> Bool in
        source.sourceType.rawValue == EKSourceType.local.rawValue
        }.first!

    // Save the calendar using the Event Store instance
    do {
        try eventStore.saveCalendar(newCalendar, commit: true)
    } catch {
        print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

When I build the project and click run it gives me the error "json error: An unexpected error occurred.". When I try to add an event to defaultcalendar it gives me an error "json error: No calendar was set". I have tried all the available sources online but couldn't find a solution. Somehow neither eventStore.save or eventStore.saveCalendar is working for me. Can someone please let me know where might I be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible reasons

1. From the documentation of [EKEventStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore)

   > To access the user’s Calendar data, all sandboxed macOS apps must include the `com.apple.security.personal-information.calendars` entitlement. To learn more about entitlements related to App Sandbox, see [Enabling App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW4).
2. Check the [authorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507239-authorizationstatus) of the store and call [requestAccess](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekeventstore/1507547-requestaccess) if necessary.

---

Your error message is misleading, the error has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Thank you so much. Enabling App Sandbox worked for me. This is what I did, Target -> Capabilities -> Turn on App Sandbox and activated "Calendar".